# Find Google adsense tags in a webpage

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I am trying to manage google Adsense using the official plugin. the plugin rejects  adding any extra ads to the page since it thinks there are more than three ads in the page. Actually, I am having only two ads there one in the header which appears on all pages and one on a sidebar widget.

Is there any way to find if there really 3 tags?
the issue is on product pages like this  http://safetyandsecuritycameras.com/wp-admin/options-general.php

the home page  http://safetyandsecuritycameras.com/ is ok

Answer (score 1):

You could try out WP QUADS a WordPress plugin for AdSense integration. It has a function to count and highlight the ads on a page to make sure that no more than the allowed ads are used.

[image]

It also allows you to limit the ads on your WordPress site to a maximum:

[image]

Details of the plugin can be found on http://wpquads.com/ 
You find the free version of the plugin on https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-adsense-reloaded/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default wordpress text widget for adsense. You can try that.

Comment: I am already using it, but I am surprised why does the plugin count AdSense tags. I wont miss with adsense polices